# While loop bash to check command rv

Tags: bash, while-loop, sh

Im having issues with checking the return values of two commands in the conditional statement of a while loop in bash.

I have the following code:

```
set e+
while ! array1=(‘getSensorValues 1’) && array2=(‘getSensorValues 2’);
do 
  echo “failed to get sensor values, retrying” 
  sleep 0.1 
done 
echo “array 1: ${array1[*]}”
echo “array 2: ${array2[*]}”
set e-
```

The function getSensorValues works and returns an array of values. It checks values that are being populated in real time. It will return 1 if the file it queries is locked by another process. So in the case where either of these functions return 1 , I want to retry in 100ms. I did this before by running each separately and getting their rv and just retrying if either are 1 but I want to do this in the least number of lines possible.

The code above does not work as the array2 variable does not get set, so the second command seems to not execute, I’m assuming because the first one passes.

Please, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: assuming you want `!` applied to combo of both function calls, the `!` currently only applies to the first function call; to apply to a combo of both function calls you want `! ( test1 && test2 )` =>  `! ( array1=( $(getSensorValues 1) ) && array2=( $(getSensorValues 2) ) )`

Comment: Your quotes are not correct, but that could just be a copying error. Always turn off "smart quotes" when posting code.

Comment: You also want `set -e` and `set +e` with the sign _before_ the option name.

Comment: @markp-fuso maybe `! { test1 && test2 ; }` instead to avoid the subshell.

Comment: @tjm3772 good point, especially in this case where OP is looking to populate a pair of arrays (ie,  if arrays are populated in a subshell then said assignments are lost upon exiting the subshell); thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

while ! gsv1=$(getSensorValues 1) || ! gsv2=$(getSensorValues 2); do
    echo 'failed to get sensor values, retrying' >&2
    sleep 0.1
done

read -r -a array1 <<<"$gsv1"
read -r -a array2 <<<"$gsv2"

declare -p array1 array2
```

- I've dropped the (corrected) `set +e` and `set -e` because the functions are run in a loop guard so non-zero returns will not trigger `errexit`.
- The `while` loop guard depends on the fact that `! { test1 && test2; }` is equivalent to `! test1 || ! test2` (one of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).
- [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) correctly complains about `array1=( $(getSensorValues 1) )` and similar ([SC2207](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2207)), so I've replaced the array assignment with a simple string assignment.  The string is then safely split into an array using `read -r -a ...`.
- I've added `>&2` to the `echo` command because diagnostic output should go to standard error.

Comment: I'd recommend replacing the `while ! test1 || ! test2` with `until test1 && test2`. It's much simpler and clearer, and avoids all the confusion about negation, De Morgan's laws, and whatnot.